# Отправка SQL запроса при изменении datagridview ячейки

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

Пишу графическое приложение для отображения базы данных. В форме лежит `DataGridView`.
Мне необходимо, чтобы при изменении содержимого ячейки (возникает ивент `CellValueChanged`) формировался SQL запрос вида:

```
UPDATE таблица1 SET **заголовок_столбца_измененной_ячейки** = **новое_значение_ячейки**  
WHERE **первый_столбец_таблицы** = **значение_этого_столбца_в_строке_изменившейся_ячейки**
```

где заключенное в двойных здездочках - данные, которые мне нужно выловить из `DataGridView`, остальное будет строковыми константами.

Сложность вот в чем: я что-то не пойму, формат `DataGridView` -- это ведь двумерный массив по сути, его элемент с индексом [0][0] это угловой элемент, лежащий между заголовками строк и столбцов, или это именно элемент внутри таблицы? Если да, то как достать заголовок столбца? Как достать новое и старое значение ячейки?

Comment: datagridview  != двумерный массив. datagridview - это контрол, у которого есть коллекция строк внутри и колонки. У каждой строки есть уже поля для ячеек. Если вы знаете индекс столбца, ищите что то вроде datagridview.columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `DataGridView` есть свойство `Columns`. У колонок есть свойство `HeaderText`.

```
private void DataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // создаём запрос
    var sql = $@"UPDATE таблица1
                 SET {dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText} = @param
                 WHERE {dataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText} = @id";

    // добавляем параметры
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param", dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", dataGridView[0, e.RowIndex].Value);

    // выполняем запрос
}
```

Значения нужно обязательно добавлять как параметры, во избежание sql-инъекций.

Синтаксис параметров различается в разных СУБД. Подкорректируйте на нужный.
В SQL Server используется `@name`. В Oracle - `:name`.

---

Значок `@` перед литералом строки означает verbatim string. То есть литерал может содержать переводы строк.

Значок `$` перед литералом строки означает *интерполированную* строку. В ней можно записывать переменные и выражения в фигурных скобках - будут подставлены их значения. Появилось в последней версии C#.

В предыдущих версиях языка можно использовать `string.Format`:

```
var sql = string.Format("UPDATE таблица1 SET {0} = @param WHERE {1} = @id",
    dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText,
    dataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText);
```

Также можно использовать конкатенацию:

```
var sql = "UPDATE таблица1 " +
    "SET " + dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText + " = @param " +
    "WHERE " + dataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText + " = @id";
```

Comment: не совсем разобрался в синтаксисе: что означает $@? параметры находятся внутри строки, они распознаются? Ну, думаю по собаке их найдут, но в запросе ведь еще 2 параметра должно быть, которые в фигурных скобках, они тоже распознаются? Вообще, у меня весь код горит красным, возможно что-то нужно подключить? Пробовал using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand, но красноты не убавилось.

Comment: @АндрейСолодовников - какие версии C#, .NET framework и Visual Studio используете?

Comment: Microsoft Visual C# 2010, .Net Framework version 4.7, старое, понимаю, но в 2015ой студии не разобрался с подключением бд из Access-а, а в разработке лабораторной работы был пример только для 10ой студии.

Comment: @АндрейСолодовников - обновил ответ.

Comment: большое спасибо!